# Retrieve SelectedValue from CheckedListBox and insert into SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I've a problem with a CheckedListBox. How can I get the SelectedValues into an update query?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim promozione As String

    dest = "INSERT INTO dbo.dest " &
               "([ID], [Cod], [SellIn], [SellOut]) " &
               "VALUES (@ID, @Cod, @SellIn, @SellOut)"

    Dim ins As New SqlDataAdapter(dest, con)
    Dim run As New SqlCommand(dest, con)
    con.Open()

    For Each Cod In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems()
        run.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ID", ComboBox1.SelectedValue))
        run.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Cod", CheckedListBox1.SelectedValue))
        run.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SellIn", DateTimePicker1.Text))
        run.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SellOut", DateTimePicker2.Text))
        run.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

When I click Button2, an error is returned:

> 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll the variable name '@ID' already declared.

Comment: what error it is throwing ?

Comment: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll   the variable name '@ID' already declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HOW TO INSERT INTO SQL QUERY MULTIPLE SELECTED ITEMS FROM A CHECKEDLISTBOX!
After tow days this is the solution:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim dest As String

    dest = "INSERT INTO dbo.dest " &
                 "([ID], [Cod], [SellIn], [SellOut]) " &
                 "VALUES (@ID, @Cod, @SellIn, @SellOut)"

    Dim ins As New SqlDataAdapter(dest, con)
    Dim run As New SqlCommand(dest, con)



        con.Open()

        For Each Cod As DataRowView In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems()
            run.Parameters.Clear()
            run.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ID", ComboBox1.SelectedValue))
            run.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Cod", Cod("IDCod"))) '<------ IDCods are the CheckedListBox1.ValueMembers'
            run.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SellIn", DateTimePicker1.Text))
            run.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SellOut", DateTimePicker2.Text))
            run.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next

        con.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You should clear parameters collections for each iteration, I believe as shown below. In fact, better way would be to create these parameters outside the loop and then just set their value in each iteration.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim promozione As String

    dest = "INSERT INTO dbo.dest " &
                 "([ID], [Cod], [SellIn], [SellOut]) " &
                 "VALUES (@ID, @Cod, @SellIn, @SellOut)"

    Dim ins As New SqlDataAdapter(dest, con)
    Dim run As New SqlCommand(dest, con)



        con.Open()

        For Each Cod In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems()
            run.Parameters.Clear()
            run.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ID", ComboBox1.SelectedValue))
            run.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Cod", CheckedListBox1.SelectedValue))
            run.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SellIn", DateTimePicker1.Text))
            run.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SellOut", DateTimePicker2.Text))
            run.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next

        con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Hes not using `Cod` either in his loop. Therefore it will always be the same. You are right about clearing  the params as well.

Comment: True, he is not using Cod which is strange, but I think he just wants to run the command for number of checked items or else there is typo where instead of CheckedListBox1.SelectedValue it should be cod.Checked.

Comment: Could you explain? if i clear the parameters, the sql query return only one selectedvalue how many checked items... cod is only a word. I'm a beginner

Comment: PS: the checkedlistbox1 are popolated by another sql select query into a dataset.

Comment: Or better yet: **define** the parameters **once**, before the loop - and only set the values into `For Each` loop - there's really no point in constantly re-creating those parameters over and over again....